# How to extract selected Object properties to the newly created property with Array type?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an JS collection (array of objects with few properties).

```
let xyz = [{
    categoryId: 1,
    categoryName: 'Test',
    programId: 112,
    programName: 'Program Test',
    value: 5050,
    value2: 1000
},
{
    categoryId: 2,
    categoryName: 'Test',
    programId: 112,
    programName: 'Program Test',
    value: 5050,
    value2: 1000
},
{
    categoryId: 3,
    categoryName: 'Test',
    programId: 112,
    programName: 'Program Test',
    value: 5050,
    value2: 1000
}]
```

How to transform such collection using LODASH to the following structure (added values property as an array of values coming from 'value' and 'value2':

```
let abc = [{
        categoryId: 1,
        categoryName: 'Test',
        programId: 112,
        programName: 'Program Test',
        values: [5050,1000]
    },
    ...
    ]
```

Comment: Will every object have one property named `value` and another named `value2`? Are those the only names you need to deal with?

Comment: Do you want to mutate the objects? Or create a copy that has the different structure? Also, have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3):

You need to transform your array using basic map operation.
Using lodash:

```
let abc = _.map(xyz, function(el) {
    return {
        categoryId: el.categoryId,
        categoryName: el.categoryName,
        programId: el.programId,
        programName: el.programName,
        values: [el.value, el.value2]
    };
});
```

But I would rather follow ["You Dont Need Lodash"](https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Lodash-Underscore#_map) trend here by using *Array.prototype.map* function

Answer (score 2):

If you look for some flexibility, and don't know all the properties your objects might have, but want to merge any `value*` property values together, then you could maybe find inspiration in this ES6 code:

```
let res = xyz.map( o => Object.assign({}, 
    ...Object.keys(o).map(key => !key.test(/^value\d*$/) && ({ [key]: o[key]})),
    { values: Object.keys(o).filter(key => key.test(/^value\d*$/)).map(key => o[key]) }
));
```

```js
let xyz = [{
    categoryId: 1,
    categoryName: 'Test',
    programId: 112,
    programName: 'Program Test',
    value: 5050,
    value2: 1000
},
{
    categoryId: 2,
    categoryName: 'Test',
    programId: 112,
    programName: 'Program Test',
    value: 5050,
    value2: 1000
},
{
    categoryId: 3,
    categoryName: 'Test',
    programId: 112,
    programName: 'Program Test',
    value: 5050,
    value2: 1000
}];

let res = xyz.map( o => Object.assign({}, 
    ...Object.keys(o).map(key => !/^value\d*$/.test(key) && ({ [key]: o[key]})),
    { values: Object.keys(o).filter(key => /^value\d*$/.test(key)).map(key => o[key]) }
));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If the order of the values is important, then inject a `sort` in the chain, just before the final `.map()`.

#### Lodash

With lodash it could look like this (sticking to ES5 code this time):

```
var res = _.map(xyz, function (o) {
    return _.set(
        _.omitBy(o, function (v, key) { return /^value\d*$/.test(key) }),
        'values', 
        _.values(_.pickBy(o, function (v, key) { 
            return /^value\d*$/.test(key)
        }))
    );
});
```

Comment: You'll want to use `test` instead of `match` for boolean predicates. Btw, I'd be more explicit about `/…/.test(key) ? null : {[key]: o[key]}` instead of abusing `&&`

Comment: Also you might want to mention that this does not respect the number in the `value*` property name, the array order could be anything.

Comment: Point taken, @Bergi. Seems you are helping me out a lot today :D NB: the ternary operator is indeed more explicit, but I have no objection against the use of `&&` in this case.

Comment: Heh, I'm just training my replacements for retirement :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with `_.merge`

```
var res = _.map(xyz, function(item) {
    return _.merge(
        {}, // to avoid xyz mutations
        _.omit(item, ['value', 'value2']), // remove useless keys
        {values: _.at(item, ['value', 'value2'])} // get needed values
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I added together all the properties that start with `"value"`, just in case.

```js
let xyz = [{
    categoryId: 1,
    categoryName: 'Test',
    programId: 112,
    programName: 'Program Test',
    value: 5050,
    value2: 1000
},
{
    categoryId: 2,
    categoryName: 'Test',
    programId: 112,
    programName: 'Program Test',
    value: 5050,
    value2: 1000
},
{
    categoryId: 3,
    categoryName: 'Test',
    programId: 112,
    programName: 'Program Test',
    value: 5050,
    value2: 1000
}]

let abc = _.map(xyz, function (obj) {
  var valuesKeys = _.filter(_.keys(obj), function (key) {
    return key.indexOf('value') === 0;
  });
  let result = _.omit(obj, valuesKeys);
  result.values = _.reduce(_.values(_.pick(obj, valuesKeys)), _.add);
  return result;
});

console.log(abc);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```